# How to comment out PHP code in HTML files selectively?

Tags: php, regex, perl, internationalization, translation

I'm trying to make mixed PHP/HTML source files ready for translation in [OmegaT](http://www.omegat.org) which is a Java translation memory application. It has a HTML filter which can deal with clean HTML files nicely, but it gets confused when PHP code is mixed in.

To avoid this issue I'm trying to come up with a solution to put the PHP code inside HTML comments (<!-- -->), so OmegaT HTML filter can ignore it.

Further complication is that the commenting should only happen when the PHP code is between the HTML tags and not when the PHP code is used to create the HTML tag attributes.

To illustrate the requirements better I would like add HTML comments around the PHP code in div id=1 and id=3, but in id=2.

Original:

```
    <body>
      <div id="1">
        <?php
          echo $var;
        ?>
      </div>
      <div id="2">
        <a href="/index.php?p=<?php echo $var; ?>" >text</a>
      </div>
      <div id="3">
        <p>Some text <?php echo $var; ?> generated partially with PHP.</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Commented:

```
    <body>
      <div id="1">
        <!--<?php
          echo $var;
        ?>-->
      </div>
      <div id="2">
        <a href="/index.php?p=<?php echo $var; ?>" >text</a>
      </div>
      <div id="3">
        <p>Some text <!--<?php echo $var; ?>--> generated partially with PHP.</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

If I comment out the PHP code in div id=2 the OmegaT HTML filter converts the <> characters to HTML elements which I would like to avoid.

I was trying to make a simple Perl script to add the comments when needed, but I failed to come up with a useful regex substitute solution.

Comment: should  searching for #>(<\?php .*?\?>)<# and replacing it by #><!-- \1 --><# work?

Comment: I've redone the examples to make it clearer what I would like to do. @JohannesH. Your regex seems to only work when the PHP code is strictly between ><, but this is not always the case in the files I have.

Comment: Yepp, in only works in those cases, as all your exmaples were that way. BUt you can use it as a base. I'll look into it again though, but it'll take a while, busy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Another, alternative, approach to the whole situation: Instead of trying to force hte document to be in a format that your translating tool can handkle, why not just work around it? Separate the strings from the PHP code, create you own XML file with the strings in it. OmegaT can handle that file. Read and parse it in PHP when generating the website instead of directly using the translated files. Much cleaner solution in my eyes...

Comment: I don't have control over the original source files. I'm only trying to translate them. Translating the actual HTML/PHP source files allows the translator to see a raw preview of the translated file locally which is big plus.

Comment: I see. Too bad. I'll try finding a regex once more then ;) Can you list all cases in which it should and should nt replaced? SInce "href" already is an exception, are there others?

Comment: It seems the inline PHP codes generating dynamic attributes in the HTML tags should not be commented out. The <a> tag was just an example and it should the case for all HTML tags.